# How to interpret base_value of GBT classifier when using SHAP?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, shap

I recently discovered [this amazing library for ML interpretability](https://github.com/slundberg/shap). I decided to build a simple xgboost classifier using a [toy dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer.html#sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer) from sklearn and to draw a `force_plot`.

To understand the plot the library says:

> The above explanation shows features each contributing to push the
> model output from the base value (the average model output over the
> training dataset we passed) to the model output. Features pushing the
> prediction higher are shown in red, those pushing the prediction lower
> are in blue (these force plots are introduced in our Nature BME
> paper).

So it looks to me as the base_value should be the same as `clf.predict(X_train).mean()`which equals 0.637. However this is not the case when looking at the plot, the number is actually not even within [0,1]. I tried doing the log in different basis (10, e, 2) assuming it would be some kind of monotonic transformation... but still not luck. How can I get to this base_value?

```
!pip install shap

from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
import pandas as pd
import shap

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
X = pd.DataFrame(data=X)
y = pd.DataFrame(data=y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(clf.predict(X_train).mean())

# load JS visualization code to notebook
shap.initjs()

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(clf)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train)

# visualize the first prediction's explanation (use matplotlib=True to avoid Javascript)
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0,:], X_train.iloc[0,:])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get `base_value` in raw space (when `link="identity"`) you need to unwind class labels --> to probabilities --> to raw scores. Note, the default loss is `"deviance"`, so the raw is inverse sigmoid:

```
# probabilites
y = clf.predict_proba(X_train)[:,1]
# raw scores, default link="identity"
y_raw = np.log(y/(1-y))
# expected raw score
print(np.mean(y_raw))
print(np.isclose(explainer.expected_value, np.mean(y_raw), 1e-12))
2.065861773054686
[ True]
```

The relevant plot for 0th data point in raw space:

```
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[0], shap_values[0,:], X_train.iloc[0,:], link="identity")
```

[image]

Should you wish to switch to sigmoid probability space (`link="logit"`):

```
from scipy.special import expit, logit
# probabilites
y = clf.predict_proba(X_train)[:,1]
# exected raw base value
y_raw = logit(y).mean()
# expected probability, i.e. base value in probability spacy
print(expit(y_raw))
0.8875405774316522
```

The relevant plot for 0th data point in probability space:

[image]

Note, the probability `base_value` from shap's perspective, what they call a baseline probability if no data is available, is not what a reasonable person would define by having no independent variables (`0.6373626373626373` in this case)

---

Full reproducible example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
import pandas as pd
import shap
print(shap.__version__)

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
X = pd.DataFrame(data=X)
y = pd.DataFrame(data=y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())

# load JS visualization code to notebook
shap.initjs()

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(clf, model_output="raw")
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train)

from scipy.special import expit, logit
# probabilites
y = clf.predict_proba(X_train)[:,1]
# exected raw base value
y_raw = logit(y).mean()
# expected probability, i.e. base value in probability spacy
print("Expected raw score (before sigmoid):", y_raw)
print("Expected probability:", expit(y_raw))

# visualize the first prediction's explanation (use matplotlib=True to avoid Javascript)
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[0], shap_values[0,:], X_train.iloc[0,:], link="logit")
```

Output:

```
0.36.0
Expected raw score (before sigmoid): 2.065861773054686
Expected probability: 0.8875405774316522
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Makes more sense now. Could you add a link to the deviance loss in the reply? I would like to see the actual formula xgboost uses and why sigmoid is the inverse.

Comment: @G.Macia you keep on referrig to xgboost while your question is about GBT classifier in scikit-learn (I have edited your title); see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html) for the default setting `loss='deviance'`

Comment: Should it be `shap_values[0,:]` or `shap_values[1,:]` in the plot(s)?

Comment: @desertnaut My understanding `0` or `1` is the row index for the data point of interest

Comment: You are right, since here you have kept only the `[:,1]` elements in `y` (i.e. probability of class 1). Regarding the `expected_value`, it is supposed to be the average prediction by the model in the underlying dataset (straightforward in regression but maybe no so much here), and not when no data is available. I agree nevertheless that this is not what most people would consider a baseline (excellent answer BTW, sorry I cannot upvote twice).