# How to show feature values in shap waterfall plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shap

Looking into the shap library, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65029216/how-to-interpret-base-value-of-multi-class-classification-problem-when-using-sha), in which the answer showcased the waterfall plot, neat! Looking at some of the official examples [here](https://notebook.community/slundberg/shap/notebooks/general/Explainable%20AI%20with%20Shapley%20Values) and [here](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/api_examples/plots/waterfall.html) I notice the plots also showcase the value of the features.

The shap package contains both `shap.waterfall_plot` and `shap.plots.waterfall`, trying both on a Random Forest trained on the Iris dataset gave the same results (see one code and image example below)

```
for which_class in y.unique():
display(
    shap.waterfall_plot(shap.Explanation(values=shap_values[int(which_class)][idx], 
                                         base_values=explainer.expected_value[int(which_class)], 
                                         feature_names=X_test.columns.tolist())
                       )
)
```

In which `idx` indicates a sample in the test set I'm trying to explain. The code generates the following plot for one of the classes:
[image]

How can I get the plot to also display the feature values? I didn't see any additional arguments I could pass to the plot method

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!

the `shap.Explanation` method has an argument where you can pass the data. See edited example below

```
for which_class in y.unique():
display(
    shap.waterfall_plot(shap.Explanation(values=shap_values[int(which_class)][row], 
                                         base_values=explainer.expected_value[int(which_class)], 
                                         data=X_test.iloc[row],  # added this line
                                         feature_names=X_test.columns.tolist())
                       )
)
```

[image]
(don't mind the slight difference in the contributions of the features compared to the image uploaded in the question, there's probably something off in setting the random seed)